# Naming convention for upper case abbreviations

Tags: java, naming-conventions, uppercase, camelcasing, abbreviation

Should a method that returns an XML stream be called

```
public Stream getXmlStream();
```

or instead

```
public Stream getXMLStream();
```

What's your opinion about that? What's considered best practice?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is no one correct answer. This [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase#Programming_and_coding) extract is helpful:

> Programming identifiers often need to contain acronyms and initialisms
>   which are already in upper case, such as "old HTML file". By analogy
>   with the title case rules, the natural camel case rendering would have
>   the abbreviation all in upper case, namely "oldHTMLFile". However,
>   this approach is problematic when two acronyms occur together (e.g.,
>   "parse DBM XML" would become "parseDBMXML") or when the standard
>   mandates lower camel case but the name begins with an abbreviation
>   (e.g. "SQL server" would become "sQLServer"). For this reason, some
>   programmers prefer to treat abbreviations as if they were lower case
>   words and write "oldHtmlFile", "parseDbmXml" or "sqlServer".

Answer (score 21):

A "convention" is just that - it's not a "rule". However, I feel strongly that `getXmlStream()` is the best option. Consider multiple such terms: compare `getSQLDBIOXML()` to `getSqlDbIoXml()`

Answer (score 15):

You should probably go for `getXmlStream`. Think of `parseDBMXML` or more complicated examples that make the code unreadable.

Comes from wikipedia [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)

Answer (score 9):

I'm not saying it `should` be this way but for some, they can automatically adjust/expect that when there's a sequential string of upper-cased letters followed by lower-cased letters there is an acronym somewhere. My **`opinion`** is to go with `getXmlStream()` --it's something that I `think` is something easier for most people to read, compared to the number of those instantly able to read `getXMLStream()` with ease..

Answer (score 0):

using `public Stream getXMLStream();` will be advisable 
Its better to keep original meaning of abbreviation