# Naming convention for initialisms and acronyms that would normally for upper case

Tags: javascript, php, naming-conventions

Does anyone know of any standards or best practices for dealing with acronyms and initialisms? (PHP and Javascript conventions would be most helpful to me but the reasoning for any language would be hepful)

Examples:

`function getXML(){}` vs `function getXml(){}`

or

`$userId` vs `$userID`

Comment: What do you mean by "initializations"?

Comment: Sorry I meant initialisms. I see how that could be a really confusing typo for this site.

Comment: What do you mean by "initialisms"? :P Have you an example?

Comment: ID and XML are technically initialisms because to say each letter.

Answer (score 1):

The conventions vary in PHP development. The answer to [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/196416/whats-the-dominant-naming-convention-for-variables-in-php-camelcase-or-undersc) will provide examples of different conventions.

I've found that most developers I've worked with follow that later convention:

```
function getXml() {}
```

and

```
$userId
```

Take a look at [this other resource](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) to learn more about PHP coding style conventions.

Comment: Did you see any references to initialisms in the PSR standards? I was scanning through them before posting here hoping to find examples of initializations. My team all agreed to use PSR for PHP code, but we seem to have differing opinions on initialisms.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Initialisms are a special case that were most likely not specified in the PSR standards due to the concerns addressed in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277355/naming-convention-for-upper-case-abbreviations).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php PHP Classes seems to keep initialisms uppercase

Comment: PHP's classes follow different naming conventions. I found [EventHttpConnection](http://php.net/manual/en/class.eventhttpconnection.php) which uses [Pascal Case](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PascalCase), instead of all caps.

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal convention for initialisms and acronyms in JavaScript.

Some examples:

- [`element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)
- [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)
- [`$animateCss`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animateCss)
- [`angular.toJson`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson)
- [`_.prototype.toJSON`](https://lodash.com/docs#prototype-value)
- [`ReactDOM.findDOMNode`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.finddomnode)
- [`_domID`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/67f8524e88abbf1ac0fd86d38a0477d11fbc7b3e/src/renderers/dom/client/ReactDOMComponentTree.js#L83)
- [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
- [`_.uniqueId`](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqueId)